# Datatable customize row

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to customize the jQuery DataTables rows, and the data comes from Ajax source, but I'm confused.

The table always shows message "No data available in table".

This is my source:

```
// table kabupaten
var tblRow ="";
var kabupaten = $('#tabel_kabupaten').DataTable();

// data table kabupaten
$.getJSON('datakabupaten', function( a ) {

    $.each(a.data, function(i, datas) {
    tblRow += "<tr>" 
                 +"<td>"+(i+1)+ "</td>" 
                 +"<td>"+datas.nama_kabupaten+ "</td>" 
                 +"<td>"+datas.keterangan+ "</td>" 
                 +"</tr>";

    }); 
    $(tblRow).appendTo("#tabel_kabupaten tbody");
});
```

Comment: What do you get from the server as a response?

Comment: That's not a good approach, you should use `ajax` source data and `colums.render` look at here https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html and here https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render

Answer (score 0):

You should use [ajax](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) and [columns.render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) options as a better approach.

Use the following code instead.

```
var kabupaten = $('#tabel_kabupaten').DataTable({
   'ajax': 'datakabupaten',
   'columns': [
      { 
         'data': null, 
         'render': function(data, type, full, meta){
            return (meta.row + 1);
         }
      },
      { 'data': 'nama_kabupaten' },
      { 'data': 'keterangan' }
   ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had a need to render custom rows as each of my rows were being displayed as a table. This will likely cause issues depending on the functionality you are using in datatables but for what I needed, it works great.

I'm also hiding the headers.

I used `createdRow` to grab the row and place my own template in it.

```
"createdRow": function (row, data, dataIndex) {
    var table = [
        '<td style="padding: 1px;">',
            '<table class="table clickable" id="' + data.ID + '" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">',
                '<tr>',
                    '<td>Facility:</td> ',
                    '<td>' + data.Facility + '</td>',
                    '<td>Person:</td>',
                    '<td>' + data.Person+ '</td>',
                '</tr>',
                '<tr>',
                    '<td>Created:</td> ',
                    '<td>' + data.Created + '</td>',
                    '<td>Phone:</td>',
                    '<td>' + data.Phone+ '</td>',
                '</tr>',
                '<tr>',
                    '<td>Status:</td> ',
                    '<td>' + data.Status+ '</td>',
                    '<td>Expected:</td>',
                    '<td>' + data.Expected + '</td>',
                '</tr>',
                // ..etc etc etc
            '</table>',
        '</td>'
    ].join("\n");
    //wrap it since I need the starting parent element
    $(row).html($(table).wrap("<div>").parent().html());
}
```